# Temporary mute command doesn't mute and throws deprecation warning

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, user-roles

I'm trying to create a temporary mute command for my Discord bot. It creates the role muted, but the user can still write messages even though I've changed the perms.
On top of that, I'm getting the following deprecation warning:

> (node:15956) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead

```
    const Discord = require("discord.js");
const ms = require("ms");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  //!tempmute @user 1s/m/h/d

  let tomute = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));
  if(!tomute) return message.reply("Couldn't find user.");
  if(tomute.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("Can't mute them!");
  let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(`name`, "muted");
  //start of create role
  if(!muterole){
    try{
      muterole = await message.guild.createRole({
        name: "muted",
        color: "#000000",
        permissions:[]
      })
      message.guild.channels.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
        await channel.overwritePermissions(muterole, {
          SEND_MESSAGES: false,
          ADD_REACTIONS: false
        });
      });
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e.stack);
    }
  }
  //end of create role
  let mutetime = args[1];
  if(!mutetime) return message.reply("You didn't specify a time!");

  await(tomute.addRole(muterole.id));
  message.reply(`<@${tomute.id}> has been muted for ${ms(ms(mutetime))}`);

  setTimeout(function(){
    tomute.removeRole(muterole.id);
    message.channel.send(`<@${tomute.id}> has been unmuted!`);
  }, ms(mutetime));


//end of module
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "tempmute"
}
```

Comment: This sounds more like a permissions issue than an issue with your bot. If you manually give the role in Discord, can the affected user still post? Important also to note that if you're testing it on - for example - yourself, it might appear not to work because server admins can always post.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem and like you said, it was the permissions. And on top of that I should have changed:

```
let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(`name`, "muted");
```

To the following:

```
let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(muterole => muterole.name === "muted");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some errors in your script so I fixed it back up for you

```
//!tempmute @user 1s/m/h/d

  let tomute = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() ||
message.guild.members.get(args[0]));   if(!tomute) return
message.reply("Couldn't find user.");  
if(tomute.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return
message.reply("Can't mute them!");   let muterole =
message.guild.roles.find(muterole => muterole.name === "muted");  
//start of create role   if(!muterole){
    try{
      muterole = await message.guild.createRole({
        name: "muted",
        color: "#000000",
        permissions:[]
      })
      message.guild.channels.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
        await channel.overwritePermissions(muterole, {
          SEND_MESSAGES: false,
          ADD_REACTIONS: false
        });
      });
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e.stack);
    }   }   //end of create role   let mutetime = args[1];   if(!mutetime) return message.reply("You didn't specify a time!");

  await(tomute.addRole(muterole.id));   message.reply(`<@${tomute.id}>
has been muted for ${message(message(mutetime))}`);

  setTimeout(function(){
    tomute.removeRole(muterole.id);
    message.channel.send(`<@${tomute.id}> has been unmuted!`);   }, message (mutetime));

//end of module }

module.exports.help = {   name: "tempmute" }
```